# Conditionally filtering an array of objects using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash, key-value

I'm currently dealing with a search API where the objects' `drive` value could either be `automatic` or `manual`.

```
var mixedResults = [{model: "328", drive: "automatic"}, {model: "328", drive: "manual"}, {model: "M4", drive: "automatic"}, {model: "M4", drive: "manual"}];

var linearResults = [{model: "328", drive: "manual"}, {model: "M3", drive: "manual"}];
```

What I'd like to do is filter all the objects that have `automatic`, save these objects to a variable, and exclude all others.

This could easily be done using the `filter`but there's a catch. If there's a scenario where the search result returns a collection where none of the objects have the value of `automatic` I'd like to save the collection of `manual` objects instead.

Comment: If you do not have `automatic` elements it means that your **entire** original collection is `manual`.

Comment: Correct. The original intention is to grab any/all objects that automatic but settle for manual objects if automatic one's don't exist.

Comment: You do the filtering. If you get empty collection, return the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the filtering and check for an empty set:

```
var mixedResults = [{model: "328", drive: "automatic"}, {model: "328", drive: "manual"}, {model: "M4", drive: "automatic"}, {model: "M4", drive: "manual"}];

var results = mixedResults.filter(function (x) {
  return x.drive === "automatic";
});

if (results.length === 0)
  results = mixedResults;
```

Comment: I edited the last line of code so there's a semicolon; I suggest you change this code to use 3 equal signs instead of 2, because no type conversion is necessary.

Comment: Curly braces aren't needed for the conditional?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Which conditional, the `if`? No, you don't need curly braces anywhere I haven't used them. The example is syntactically correct.

Comment: @TheWobbuffet I'm used to CoffeeScript where `==` is identical to `===`. I almost wrote `results = mixedResults if results.length == 0` :|

Comment: @meagar you gotta love coffeescript

Comment: @meagar Out of curiosity how come the `if` conditional wasn't placed inside the `filter` function so that all would take place within one action?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Because the filter has to be completely finished before we know if it found any matching elements. The `filter` is simply responsible for producing a list of 0 or more matching objects. You have to finish producing this list, and checking every input element before you know if there are no matches.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Edwin If you want to suggest an ES6 solution, post it as an additional answer

Comment: @meagar I was only extending your answer.